# Javascript and HTML. How to make alerts show up on an HTML form instead alert boxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am fairly new to Javascript and I am trying to integrate this Javascript code with HTML. At the moment, when you run the script in the browser, it asks 5 math questions, shows how many you got correct, and then displays 5 alert boxes showing the question, your answer, the correct answer, and whether or not you are correct. Now what I want to do is instead of this information showing up in alert boxes, I want all of the questions to show up in HTML instead.

So the output on HTML would look something like [**THIS.**](http://jsfiddle.net/kxtjb2Lx/) <---

And here is the javascript code I have so far

```
<script>
function ask() {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var op = ["*", "+", "/", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];

    return {
            question : "How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?",
            ansGiven: prompt("How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?"),
            ansCorrect : eval( a + op + b),
            get isCorrect(){return this.ansGiven == this.ansCorrect}
           };
}

var questions = [ask(), ask(), ask(), ask(), ask()]
    total = questions.length,
    correct = questions.filter(function(ans){return ans.isCorrect}).length;

window.alert( "You got "+correct+"/"+total+" correctly");
questions.forEach(function(q, i){
    alert("Question " +(i+1)+ " : " + q.question 
    + "\nAnswer: " + q.ansGiven 
    + "\nCorrect Answer: " + q.ansCorrect 
    + "\nYou were " + ((q.isCorrect)?"Correct!":"Wrong!"));
});

</script>
```

And you can test out the javascript code [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/atg5y5zr/)

I know you probably have to use a form layout. But I'm not sure how to show the same message layouts that appear on the alerts, to show up in the same format, but as a list in html, so it shows all of the questions, not just one at a time. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using jquery with your function and use the `.html()` function, and the `append()` function.

`html()` will set the elements contents to be whatever you tell it to be. IE:

```
$('#question').html("<p>" + questionNum + ". What is " + equation + "?</p><input type='number' name='input'><br><input type='submit' value='Check Ans'>");
```

And then for each of your results you may want to do

```
$('#results').append("<p>Question " + questionNum + " : How much is " + equation + "? - " + result + "</p>");
```

Your html could look like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='question'></div>
    <div id='answer'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Your final result would end up being something like:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id='question'>
      <p>5. What is 4 / 2?</p><input type='number' name='input'><br>
      <input type='submit' value='Check Ans'>
    </div>
    <div id='answer'>
      <p>Question 1 : How much is 1 + 2? - You were right!</p>
      <p>Question 2 : How much is 9 * 21? - You were wrong!</p>
      <p>Question 3 : How much is 1 + 42? - You were right!</p>
      <p>Question 4 : How much is 32 - 9? - You were right!</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit: JSFiddle**

[I didn't have a limit of 4 question and then a stop like you have, but it does work purely with HTML.](http://jsfiddle.net/4o8gfdqr/)

The function uses two `append()`s on line 17 and 19, one for correct and the other for incorrect. With this it will make the next answer added to the bottom of the div. IE: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, etc etc. After answering so many question the latest will disappear off the screen. If you want the latest question show at the top, IE: 7, 6, 5... then change both appends to `prepend()`.

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to make this a working demo using [JSFiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @James Appended a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: Nice! Would a way to make it stop at a certain number, do you think a for loop would do it? So it stops when it reaches 5 and sends out a message saying you've finished your test?

Comment: Okay. So this may be a bad question, but when I save all of this to an html document. The page does not load. I notice you used jquery to run the program. How do you implement jquery into an html document. I've downloaded jquery 1.11.0 and wrapping the script with <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script> **code** </script> However, this does not work for me.

Comment: I normally go with the option of loading jquery from googles hosted libraries so that I don't have to download anything. ``<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>``. Make sure to put that in the head tag. If you're using Chrome, (something I often do), rightclick the page and view source code. Then click 'console' tab. Any javascript errors will be there.

Comment: Ah, I see. I also put the window.onload = function() {  at the beginning of all the code and an ending bracket to make it work as well. You were extremely helpful to me and I thank you for spending your time to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Those message boxes are actually native dialogs, part of your web browser that call out to the operating system. You can't directly do what you're looking for. However, you can replace them with a pure-JS modal window from one of the many toolkits out there today like Twitter Bootstrap.

http://bootboxjs.com/ is an example of doing just about what you're describing.

Answer (score 0):

[try this](http://jsfiddle.net/kxtjb2Lx/1/)

```
function ask() {
    var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
    var op = ["*", "+", "/", "-"][Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];

    return {
            question : "How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?",
            ansGiven: prompt("How much is " + a + " " + op + " " + b + "?"),
            ansCorrect : eval( a + op + b),
            get isCorrect(){return this.ansGiven == this.ansCorrect}
           };
}

var questions = [ask(), ask(), ask(), ask(), ask()]
    total = questions.length,
    correct = questions.filter(function(ans){return ans.isCorrect}).length;

var result= "<h1>result</h1><br/>You got "+correct+"/"+total+" correctly<br/>";
questions.forEach(function(q, i){
    result+=("Question " +(i+1)+ " : " + q.question 
    + "\nAnswer: " + q.ansGiven 
    + "\nCorrect Answer: " + q.ansCorrect 
    + "\nYou were " + ((q.isCorrect)?"Correct!":"Wrong!"))+"<br/>";
});
document.write(result);
```